# Vuejs: Using get and set property inside computed object in vuejs displays an error

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuex

Is declaring property (get() and set()) inside computed object is not allowed in vuejs?

The code works, however vscode shows tons of red color in the display, see screenshot for reference.

I'm not sure if vuejs or vscode triggers the error.

Farmer.js component

```
computed: {
        ...mapState("farmers", ["crud_step"]),
        normal_data(){ //this works
              return 'test';
        },
        step: { //this also works but this line causes an error display
            get() {
              return this.crud_step;
            },
            set(value) {
              return this.SET_CRUD_STEP(value);
            }
          },
      },
```

farmer.js store

```
const state = {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  crud_step: 1,
  ...

};

const mutations = {
  SET_CRUD_STEP(state, value){
    state.crud_step = value;
  },
 ...
};
```

Note: eslint is disabled

Repo Link: https://github.com/juanPao/acms/blob/main/src/components/Farmers/FarmerCreate.vue
[image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve] reproducing the errror. Use codesandbox.io if you need a node-like multi-file editor and only include the minimum amount of code to repro the bug. Pictures of code are useless. Only code is useful. Provide enough of it to make the problem reproducible, which you haven't, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computed doesn't look right. First off, you shouldn't return anything from the `setter`. It's an action. It's the `getter` which has to return a value.

And you want the `setter` to `commit` the mutation. So your code could look like:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState("farmers", ["crud_step"]),
  step: {
    get() {
      return this.crud_step;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit('farmers/SET_CRUD_STEP', value);
    }
  }
}
```

..., which makes it obvious you don't actually need two local props (`crud_step` and `step`), you can simply map the store's `crud_step` onto a local `step`:

```
computed: {
  step: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.farmers.crud_step;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit('farmers/SET_CRUD_STEP', value);
    }
  }
}
```

For consistency, I'd actually name the local property `crud_step` (which implies you have to also change it in the `<template>`). In the long run, sticking to consistent and clean naming patterns (whatever yours happen to be) will increase your efficiency in both coding and debugging.

---

Since you haven't shown all the code in your component, I guessed you don't have a method called `SET_CRUD_STEP` which commits the mutation. Even if you do, it's unnecessary. You can simply commit from the `setter`. And if you used that method somewhere else in the component, replace it with `this.step = someValue` (which invokes the setter - that's what a setter is: a function which gets called when you assign something to that property).

Comment: thankyou for answering, I tried your code and it also works. but still the error displays in vscode. 108 out of 108 error, the problem says 'Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance'... maybe my vscode setup is the one that causes the error. later i'l try to upload the code in github.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `TypeScript`. In this case you have to type the values: 
`step: { get(): number { return /* stuff */ }, set(value: number) { /* commit stuff */ } }`. Note that you need to type all your computed to make the errors go away and sometimes Vue wrongly reports the type annotation failure in the first method in your `methods`. That's one of the TS problems Vue 2 has and which Vue 3 will no longer have.

Comment: I'm using regular js, heres the link to the repo: https://github.com/juanPao/acms/blob/main/src/components/Farmers/FarmerCreate.vue

Comment: Your expectation I'm going to clone a repo and build it on my machine to check some error is unrealistic. Besides, we're not using the same IDE. If you are able to repro the issue into an online multi-file editor, such as codesandbox.io, I will have a look and probably be able to procure a fix.

Comment: I see why `this.SET_CRUD_STEP` also works in your case: you're mapping the store mutations onto your component (which creates a method with the same name as the mutation). This works but can get messy once you start using more than one module. I tend to limit the usage of mappers to avoid confusion and call the exact mutation I want from the setter, as demoed above. As for your IDE errors, unless you provide more info and/or a way to repro, I can't really help. I can only fix what I can see.

Comment: thankyou very much, I now found the problem that causes the error. I disabled Vetur extension in vscode, and the error gone.